# Access a component's children props outside the parent component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a main page component in react whose render function looks like this

```
const MainPage = () => {
    return (
         <>
              <Component1 />
              <Component2 />
         </>
    )
}
```

And Component has some inputs

```
const Component1 = () => {
    const [val1, setVal1] = React.useState("");
    const [val2, setVal2] = React.useState("");
    return (
         <>
              <input type="text" value={val1} onChange={setVal1} />
              <input type="text" value={val2} onChange={setVal2} />
         </>
    )
}
```

My question is how to get values val1 and val2 in the MainPage component?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I feel you cant do it that way, you should have the state values in the MainPage component, or if you need to make use of that values you have to make use of the context API

Comment: @Nacho I believed this method will result in unnecessary prop drilling. So wanted to make sure if there's any other better method.

Answer (score 0):

use Redux or Context API in your React Project. Btw you can call the function to get the children component variables value.

Example React using Class

```js
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      value: ''
    };
  }

  //...

  handleChangeValue = e => this.setState({value: e.target.value});

  //...

  render() {
    return (
      <Child
        value={this.state.value}
        onChangeValue={this.handleChangeValue}
      />
    );
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  //...

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        value={this.props.value}
        onChange={this.props.onChangeValue}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont know how this solves my problem. You have just maintained the state in parent component level and passing it as props to children

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
React is based on `Unidirectional Data Flow`

So to solve your problem you must define an event that will be called from the children.

```
const MainPage = () => {
    const [val1, setVal1] = React.useState("");
    const [val2, setVal2] = React.useState("");
    return (
         <>
              <Component1 val1={val1} onChange1={setVal1} val2={val2} onChange2={setVal2} />
              <Component2 />
         </>
    )
}
```

And Component1

```
const Component1 = ({val1, onChange1, val2, onChange2}) => {
    return (
         <>
              <input type="text" value={val1} onChange={onChange1} />
              <input type="text" value={val2} onChange={onChange2} />
              />
         </>
    )
}
```

Comment: I already know this method. I thought this involves unnecessary prop drilling. Thanks for the info. Will continue this approach only